# global variables from separate functions?

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I've been trying to understand the behaviour of `global` variables in Python. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them), I gather that I can **read** any variable defined in an **outer scope**. If I want to **modify** it in an **inner scope**, I have to "declare" as `global` in that ***inner*** scope, so that Python looks for it according to its [scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) and knows I'm not creating a new local variable.

But why does the following correctly print the values of variables `a` and `b`?

```
import sys

def func1():
    print a # will print 1
    print b # will print 2
    return

def main():
    global a 
    a = 1
    global b
    b = 2
    func1()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    status = main()
    sys.exit(status)
```

Comment: Because those variables *are* `global`...!?

Comment: So it's not only a matter of scope: I just have to declare it as global somewhere in my code, and I can access it everywhere?

Comment: You declare `global a`, so Python sets it as global variable. The same as if you had declared the variable outside the function in the first place.

Comment: Does python use both dynamic and lexical scope?

Comment: Yes, you can use it everywhere(except out of this file :P)

Comment: OK, great!  I thought it only worked in the way described in the first link in my post.

Comment: And you also can write `global a` everywhere, only need before you define the `a`.